# How do you reference example request body in rAML?

Tags: raml

Is it possible to reference a json block from within the same rAML file for request/response examples? From the spec there does not appear to be a way to do this other than having an external file; but I'd like to have the example and schema live next to each other if possible. Much like how you can use schema:

```
schemas:
  - awesomeSchema: |
      { ... }
# Is this possible?
examples: | 
  - awesomeExample: |
      { ... }

/awesome:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
       body:
          application/json:
            schema: awesomeSchema
            example: awesomeExample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible in RAML 1.0, have a look at https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/107

Comment: Good to hear. I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not part of the spec, it's actually supported, since RAML is a superset of YAML which does have a [syntax for DRY-ing repeated blocks](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760545). Quoting the spec:

> Repeated nodes (objects) are first identified by an anchor (marked with the ampersand - “&”), and are then aliased (referenced with an asterisk - “*”) thereafter.

Applying that to your example:

```
/awesome:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
       body:
          application/json:
            example: &awesomeExample |
              {
                id: 123,
                type: "foobar"
              }
/delicious:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: *awesomeExample
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was more looking for a way to define the Schema and Example side by side or at least near each other. Is it possible to create the anchor at the root of the document or at least outside of a resource definition?

Comment: AFAIK, `RAML` does not (yet?) allow custom properties to be hanging in the spec, and I cannot think of a standard `RAML` property that's outside the resource definitions and can elegantly hold the examples. The spec is pretty much a WIP, I encourage you to submit an issue to the project on github with your use case: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec